# Can I use any type of wifi antenna extension cable for dual-band signals?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, network-adapter, antenna

I've a wifi network card capable of dual-band signals. The card is able to connect to either the 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz signals from the router.

As the antennas are attached to the card behind the desktop casing, I'm planning to get antenna extension cables hoping that by extending the antennas they can receive stronger signals.

However, do extension cables affect the antennas' dual-band ability or even worsen the signal quality? Do I've to be concern about what kind or type of antenna extension cables I'm getting?

I'm worried that getting a generic antenna extension cable would end up limiting the network card to receive only the 2.4ghz signals.

Comment: Extensions do reduce signal quality because they attenuate the signal. Higher quality cable is generally thicker - so harder to work with, and more expensive. Im not an expert on frequency responses and signals, but i'm reasonably confudent that cable is not tuned for a given frequency, so cables which conduct 5 gig signals should be fine for 2.4 gig ones (but this is orobably less true of antennas). What distance are you planning on running the cables, how large/directional are your antennas and how far is yourshot/radius?

Comment: Well, at the moment, the signals are terrible weak even though my desktop is only at most 10 metres away from the router. But my desktop is in a pretty bad corner of the room with lots of walls and other items around it. My plan is to extend the antennas out of the corner for better signals. Most extension cables don’t state they work for 2.4 or 5.0. That’s why I’m worried whether any antennas would work particularly with 5ghz signals.

Comment: Have you considered instead getting a USB wifi adaptor and putting it on a cable (or just using ethernet instead)?

Comment: @davidgo I would have thought that a PCI-E is faster than a usual usb3? I’m hoping that an antenna extension cable would work though because it’s at least cheaper than buying a new usb WiFi adapter.